# How can I root my Verizon Galaxy Note 5?

Tags: root-access

I want to root my Verizon note 5 what's the best way to without messing up my phone or regretting it? I have done it before and regretted doing it. I want the apps and I want to like my phone too

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no root currently available for Verizon variants of the note 5. This is due to a completely locked down boot-loader and anti root protection from Samsung Knox.

It is conceivable that there will never be a root for this particular phone.

Source: http://www.xda-developers.com/root-twrp-available-for-samsung-galaxy-note-5/

Answer (score 0):

ACTUALLY, you can root the Note 5. I found a very convincing video. Check out the link.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=epLA2EjGXTg

Comment: Wow I think I can do it

Comment: Let me know if it worked!

Comment: It's probably a sprint or other variant. The Verizon one is not possible.  Source: http://www.xda-developers.com/root-twrp-available-for-samsung-galaxy-note-5/